# How to completely clear everything from an arduino and print something new?

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-ide, c++, lcd

I'm in progress of making a stickman rush game, Until I hit a bug that I have been stuck on. I want to make a if statement that states "If the stickman and the object are in the same place, clear everything and print "Game over." But when i do this, the object is still there. I tried using "lcd.clear()" but it doesnt seem to affect anything. Is there another way to fix this?

Code:

```
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>


LiquidCrystal lcd(2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7);

byte customChar[] = {
  B01110,
  B01110,
  B01110,
  B00100,
  B01110,
  B10101,
  B00100,
  B01010
};

byte gameObstical[] = {
  B11111,
  B11111,
  B11111,
  B11111,
  B11111,
  B11111,
  B11111,
  B11111
};



int vX = A0;
int vY = A1;
int sw = 8;

int xPosition = 0;
int yPosition = 0;
int SW_state = 0;
int mapX = 0;
int mapY = 0;

int screenWidth = 16;
int screenHeight = 2;


void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);

  pinMode(vX, INPUT);
  pinMode(vY, INPUT);
  pinMode(sw, INPUT_PULLUP);


  lcd.begin(16, 2);
  lcd.createChar(0, customChar);
  lcd.home();
  lcd.write(byte(0));

  lcd.createChar(1, gameObstical);


}

void loop() {


  int stickManPosition = 0;
  int obsticalPosition = 0;
  int stickManRow = 0;
  int obsticalRow = 0;

  int obsticalPosition2 = 0;
  int obsticalRow2 = 0;

  for (obsticalPosition = 15; obsticalPosition >= 0; obsticalPosition--) {
    lcd.setCursor(obsticalPosition, obsticalRow);
    lcd.write(byte(1));
    lcd.print(" ");
    delay(150);





    xPosition = analogRead(vX);
    yPosition = analogRead(vY);
    SW_state = digitalRead(sw);
    mapX = map(xPosition, 20, 1003, -500, 500);

    Serial.println("-----------");
    Serial.println(mapX);
    Serial.println(SW_state);
    Serial.println("-----------");



    if (mapX > 200) {

      lcd.clear();
      lcd.setCursor(stickManPosition, stickManRow);
      lcd.write(byte(0));

    } else if (mapX < -200) {

      stickManRow = 1;

      lcd.clear();
      lcd.setCursor(stickManPosition, stickManRow);
      lcd.write(byte(0));
    }




    if (stickManPosition == obsticalPosition) {
      if (stickManRow == obsticalRow) {

        lcd.clear()
        lcd.print("Game Over...");
        delay(150);

      }

      if (obsticalPosition == 12) {

        for (obsticalPosition2 = 11; obsticalPosition2 >= 0; obsticalPosition2--) {
          obsticalRow2 = 1;

          lcd.setCursor(obsticalPosition2, obsticalRow2);
          lcd.write(byte(1));
          lcd.print(" ");
          delay(150);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Any ideas? Thanks for reading.

Comment: You could just make `setCursor(0,0);`, print sixteen spaces and repeat it for the second row... But I'm sure there's a better way.

Comment: I've not intensively looked over your sketch. But, is it possible that the screen is really cleared with `lcd.clear()`. "Game over" is visible for less than 150 milliseconds and then other code in the loop function overwrites it with the stickman again. 150 ms is a very short time. Would you please change the `delay(150)` after the clear to let's say `delay(3000);`. To see if my guess is true?

Comment: You need to distinguish between someone actively playing a game and the game being over. You really need to implement a *finite state machine*.

Comment: you should create a condition to write objects, If game is over then dont draw objects else draw objects. or after your game is over create an infinite loop and get button push for break loop.